# Текстовый квест на Python с использованием Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

**Пытаюсь сделать квест на Python с использованием Kivy. Сделал рабочую версию через терминал с управлением через ввод вариантов ответа**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Далее сделал GUI с выводом в консоль по нажатию кнопок:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне запустить GUI вместе с основным кодом, чтобы нажатие кнопок GUI запускало команды первой программы?**

**Или мне придется переписывать всю игру заново, в самом GUI опираясь на команды из kivy?**

Answer (score 0):

Данное взаимодействие должно было быть продумано изначально. В данный момент, самым простым решением будет запуск "движка игры" после запуска киви ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664181/how-do-i-run-a-function-once-the-form-is-loaded-kivy ). Но перед этим, необходимо переопределить функции print & input таким образом, чтобы они взаимодействовали с интерфейсом киви.

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что я искал :)